# Using Sencha Touch charts within an MVC application

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-charts

I'm new to Ext.JS and sencha touch and am having a little trouble adding charts to one of my applications. I've followed the MVC [tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap) from the website and for each of my views I've ended up with something like this:

```
app.views.ViewName = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {

    dockedItems: [...],

    initComponent: function() {
        ...
        app.views.ViewName.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

What I want to do is custom drawing within the panel using Ext.draw but can't seem to get it to work. Where should I call the renderFrame() method to perform drawing and where should the code to define what is to be drawn go? If anyone could provide a small example that would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Sencha's MVC with PhoneGap example is quite advanced for a first strike at sencha. you might want to have a look at these [[part 1]](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-1/) [[part 2]](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-2/) [[part 3]](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-3/) [[part 4]](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-4/)

If you have a site working but your charts are not rendering, make sure that the chart's container as layout (layout: 'fit' or any other layout)